# performance testStopping in between

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running load test using 2 transactions in jmeter ,for 60mins with 20 users
now the things is sometimes just transaction 1 runs for 20 users but transaction 2 runs for just 3-4 users. The same incident is repeating even if i am runng the test for 15 mins or 20 mins.sometimes the test stops in between without completing 60mins run.[Screenshot of My Test Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhaTV.png)

Comment: Can you post your test plan and edit your question ?

Comment: Can you please spend some time formatting your question so it's more clear and convenient to read? As it was posted, it's not readable.